# Linux Firefox copy/paste issue

Tags: linux, firefox, mouse, fedora

I'm using Firefox 15.0.1 on Fedora 17 without running gnome or kde.

The problem I'm having is that whenever I select text outside of Firefox, for instance in xterm, the middle mouse button doesn't copy it inside Firefox, for instance in a text area, but rather brings up a context menu.

A related problem is that whenever I middle click inside Firefox, for instance in a text input, the middle mouse button brings up a menu when I'd like it to paste. Even if I select Paste in the menu not the selected text (from outside Firefox) gets pasted but the last selected text inside Firefox.

In about:config I tried "middlemouse.paste true" and also "middlemouse.paste false" together with the add-on Auto Copy but no combination worked. A middle mouse click always brings up a context menu. But the Auto Copy did help with automatically copying selected text to the clipboard. With Auto Copy the only problem I still have is pasting by middle button.

Follow up: somehow the problem solved itself. After removing Auto Copy firefox works as I expect it to (as any X application). I can't figure out why it was not doing it before, probably I was messing too much with about:config and not restarting frequently enough.

Comment: You should check if some of the add-ons is interfering with the normal middle mouse button behaviour

Comment: I believe none of my addons do that, at least they shouldn't :) I have status-4-evar, oldbar, jsonview, firebug.

Comment: I am assuming this happens only in Firefox. Try disabling all addons, restarting Firefox and see what happens. If this still occurs, then it is not the addons issue.
EDIT: my middlemouse.paste is set to true and everything works as intended. If i put it to false, paste doesn't work and no menu pops out.

Comment: I removed the Auto Copy addon and now everything works as expected :) Don't ask me how, I don't get it either, the only reason I installed Auto Copy was to have this feature but now it works without it. Probably I didn't restart firefox soon enough after making changes to about:config or something.

Comment: I am glad that you managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> Even if I select Paste in the menu not the selected text (from outside Firefox) gets pasted but the last selected text inside Firefox.

X has up to three clipboards: Primary, Secondary and Clipboard. Clicking the middle button pastes the content of Primary, selecting *paste* from the context menu pastes the content of Clipboard.

To copy something to Clipboard rather than Primary, you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> ( + <kbd>Shift</kbd> ) + <kbd>C</kbd> or select *copy* in the context menu.

Comment: And there is no way to copy from Primary in firefox?

Comment: I'm sure there is. This was meant to be a partial answer, since I don't know how to fix the other issue. Middle-clicking works fine for me, but I'm using Ubuntu with Gnome.